# Codeigniter routes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I have following url:

```
http://localhost.com/phpdemo/sbid/account/sign2?oauth_token=A2nuio32nn123oiiooiETUI8RT&oauth_verifier=AA22EE44RRR55SDFSdsf23423

Base Url : http://localhost.com/phpdemo/sbid/
```

How can I write a route that above mentioned url should be redirected/rerouted to following url :

```
http://localhost.com/phpdemo/sbid/user/login
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're mixing up CI routes and htaccess rewrites. CI routes map a url structure to a controller method, htaccess rewrites redirect urls to other urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rewriterule ^phpdemo/sbid/user/login$ phpdemo/sbid/account/sign2?oauth_token=A2nuio32nn123oiiooiETUI8RT&oauth_verifier=AA22EE44RRR55SDFSdsf23423 [L]
```

Comment: what should I replace if:  1-"oauth_token" and "oauth_verifier" values are frequently changed. 2- I want to take values of these variables to "user/login" page also

Comment: @Simpanoz, well in that case I don't think there is a possible way to rewrite buddy . .

Answer (score 0):

Add to your routes.php the following sentences:

```
$route['account/sign2?(:any)'] = 'user/login/$1';
```

So, your login function is going to look like this:

```
function login($param){
   // $param = "sign2?oauth_token=A2nuio32nn123oiiooiETUI8RT&oauth_verifier=AA22EE44RRR55SDFSdsf23423"
}
```

You need to parse this string to take params and its values.